# How to navigate to the home page from login after successful login with credentials in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular2-routing

In my angular application I have the json data having user credentials which is cretaed as .json file in angular application as

**usercredentials.json**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Admin",
        "permission": "all",
        "password": "Admin"
    },
    {
      "name": "MyName",
      "permission": "none",
      "password": "test"
    }
]
```

it will navigate to home page only if the credentials are correct(i.e username:Admin and password:Admin)

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {

  private httpOptions: any;
  public profile: any;
  public username: string;
  public password : any;
  public usr :any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    
    return this.http.post('./app/usercredentials.json', { username, password })

  }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
constructor(private ds: AuthService, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  public userinfo: any = [];
  public name:string;
  public password:any;
  public username :string;
  public user : any;
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
this.ds.login(this.username,this.password)
      .subscribe((userinfo) => {
        this.userinfo = userinfo;

        console.log('obj', this.userinfo);
        this.name = this.userinfo.name;
        this.password = this.userinfo.password;
        localStorage.setItem('user',this.name);
        localStorage.setItem('passwrd',this.password);
        if(localStorage.getItem('user')){
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);

        }

      },

        err => {
          console.log("Error", err)
        }
      );


  }
```

**login.component.html**

```
 <form>
        <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="uname" placeholder="Username" ><br>
        <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="pw" placeholder="Password" ><br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Submit">
      </form>
```

My requirement is ...
Navigate to the home page upon successful authentication and
for  unsuccess full attempt of login show error message.

Comment: How are you validating that the credentials are correct? All I can see from your question is that you are POSTing to a JSON file.

Comment: Yes,I have to validate the json data and store it in the local variable,if it is correct it has to navigate to home page

Answer (score 1):

You should use **route guards for your routes**

Please refer to this link [Route Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access)

**example,**

In your routes

```
{
  path: '/home-page',
  component: HomePageComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
}
```

And add AuthGuard class,

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
     const user = sessionStorage.getItem('user');

     if (user == null) {
       return of(this.router.createUrlTree(['login']));
     }

    return of(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam, Can you please help me for navigating to home page based on user credentials(json data)

Comment: @user If i'm understanding your correctly, You can use different conditions here and return  return of(this.router.createUrlTree(['<your desired page>']));